# How to customize \titlepage in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm trying build my own theme to use for work-related presentations in `beamer`. I'm not so familiar with how to write the themes, I'm customizing a title page manually at the moment.

What I want to do is have fine control over where text goes on the page when the `\titlepage` command is issued. I want to shift it rightwards and downwards from where `beamer` is choosing to put it.

Answer (score 87):

You could use `\defbeamertemplate` to define your own title page template. There you may use the commands `\inserttitle`, `\insertauthor`, `\insertdate` etc. to insert those values, also don't forget to use the predefined font and color values.

Here is a compilable example. Of course you can use `\centering`, `\vfill`, `beamercolorbox` etc. but I keep it simple for the purpose of demonstration.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
  \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
  \bigskip
  \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
  \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
  \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}
\title{A customized title page}
\subtitle{for demonstration}
\author{Stefan Kottwitz}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: customized title page]

Answer (score 0):

Since beamer version 3.70, the title page is structured much more modularly. Instead of one monolithic code block, it now consists of several smaller templates. This means you can do a lot of tweaks just by changing or modifying these templates.

Examples:

- to add the name of a supervisor below the author, you can use

  ```
  \addtobeamertemplate{author}{}{Supervisor\par}
  ```
- to change the spacing above the date:

  ```
  \addtobeamertemplate{date}{\vskip1cm}{}
  ```
- to change the order in which the various fields are shown on the title page:

  ```
  \setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \vbox{}
    \vfill
    \begingroup
      \centering
      \usebeamertemplate{title}
      \vskip0.5em
      \usebeamertemplate{titlegraphic}
      \vskip1em
      \usebeamertemplate{author}
      \usebeamertemplate{institute}
      \usebeamertemplate{date}
    \endgroup
    \vfill
  }
  ```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \usebeamertemplate{title}
    \vskip0.5em
    \usebeamertemplate{titlegraphic}
    \vskip1em
    \usebeamertemplate{author}
    \usebeamertemplate{institute}
    \usebeamertemplate{date}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}

\addtobeamertemplate{author}{}{Supervisor\par}
\addtobeamertemplate{date}{\vskip1cm}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]