# How to insert logo in LyX beamer?

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am trying to make presentation by using LyX beamer template (already installed in program files). But I am not able in insert a university logo on title page. Hope that some one can solve this problem.
Please download any lyx file from the link below and try to insert your own logo.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/solutions/conference-talks

I have followed the instruction given in the file.

> "If you have a file called "institution-logo-filename.xxx", where xxx is a graphic format that can be processed by latex or pdflatex, resp., then you can add a logo by uncommenting the following:"

```
%\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{institution-logo}{institution-logo-filename}
%\logo{\pgfuseimage{institution-logo}}
```

I have uncommented these two lines and have the logo file with same name "institution-logo-filename" in the same folder, but it does not work.

Comment: First, I think [tex.se] would be a better place for this; I've flagged for a moderator to migrate, perhaps one will agree you'll have better luck over there. Second, they'll probably need more information. How exactly are you trying to insert the logo? What file format is it stored in? What does the generated TeX look like?

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate from [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34740/how-to-insert-logo-on-lyx-beamer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add a logo to the titlepage, you can use the `\titlegraphic` command in the preamble. Go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

```
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics{uni-logo-filename}}
```

However, this can also be done from within the GUI. Add a new line after the author(s), and choose `TitleGraphic` from the drop down menu in the top left. Then you can add the logo as you normally add images, by clicking [image: add graphic].

For me, this placed the logo at the bottom of the page. If the same happens for you, you probably have to redefine the `title page` template. Stefan Kottwitz provides the basic idea in [How to customize \titlepage in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/how-to-customize-titlepage-in-beamer/25318#25318)

Copy the `\defbeamertemplate` part to your LaTeX preamble in Document --> Settings, and change it to suit your needs. I'm not sure exactly what you want to have, but the following produced something very similar to the template, only with the logo between the authors and the affiliations.

```
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{\centering
 \setbeamercolor{title}{bg=blue,fg=white}
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true,shadow=true,sep=5pt,center]{title}
 \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\insertsubtitle
  \end{beamercolorbox} \par\medskip
  \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par\medskip
  \inserttitlegraphic \par\medskip
  \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par\medskip
  \setbeamerfont{date}{size=\large}
  \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but It will put the logo on the corner of each slide. I need the logo on front page between the author and university name.

Comment: @user4299 Yes, I believe that is the point of `\logo`. I didn't see that you mentioned the title page in your question though, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

More information would definitely be helpful - particularly what you have tried already. Not knowing this, I take a shot:

Assuming you want to insert between subtitle and author, you could create an emtpy line there and, from the menu, select `< Insert | Graphics >` and choose your logo file. Right click on the picture and edit the settings - scale for the right size and anchor for centering.

Does that help?