# Beamer: strange behaviour of textpos on title page

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm working on a customized template for LaTeX beamer. It's finished, except for some strange behaviour of textpost on the title page. Sample code:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.5cm,.96\textheight)
This text should not appear on the title sheet.
\end{textblock*}}

\begin{document}

\title{Some title}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some frame title}
Some text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

It looks like the title page has two footers! But I don't want *any headers or footers* on my title page. I stumbled upon the option `[plain]`, i.e. `\begin{frame}[plain]`

This results in:

[image]

So even though this gives a better result, there is still one footer left. It has something to do with the `textpos` package. I really need the options `absolute` and `overlay` for some other things in my template, so changing this is not an option. I was thinking about adding this text to the frametitle -- instead of the footline -- using `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}`, but this is not a very clean solution.

Any ideas how to fix this? Since I'm creating the title page from scratch, is there an option to clear the entire title page? Or anything like `\pagestyle{empty}`?

**[Edit]** Or any way to add a logo in the bottom right corner and some text in the bottom left corner *without* using `textpos` is welcome! But keep in mind that it shouldn't be *exactly* in the corners, there must be some whitespace around it.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Why are you adding texpos textblocks within the footer? If you want some free floating text block in some position on the title page, you just put `\begin{textblock*}` inside the frame.

Comment: No, it's the other way around. In my template there are two blocks in the footer: the name of my department (text) and a logo (PDF). Since I want full control of their position, I decided to use the `textpos` package. These two blocks should NOT appear in the title page.

Comment: While I find a more elegant solution, you can move the `\addtobeamertemplate` code after the frame containing the title and this will solve the problem.

Comment: Well a very inelegant solution is just to put a white rectangular tikzpicture overlay to hide the text/logo :P

Have you checked out [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/how-to-customize-titlepage-in-beamer)?

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions. Are there perhaps other ways to control the position of objects in the footer?

Comment: @Ailurus: perhaps if you tell us what exactly should go in the footline (you already mentioned some text and a logo, but in what positions? do you need some color background for the footline?), we could suggest you some alternatives not involving `textpos`. So, please give us a full description of the desired look for the footline.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: in the bottom right corner, there should be a logo (but _with_ some whitespace between the logo and the edge). In the bottom left corner, there should be a text (and again, some whitespace between the text and the edge). Perhaps I could use `\logo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need the `textpos` package to design your footline; you can use a `beamercolorbox` having a width equal to `\paperwidth`; the options `leftskip` and `rightskip` let you specify the left and right skips, respectively, and the `sep` option allows you to introduce some extra space around the contents.

Here's a little example (the command `\FootlineText` will contain the text that should appear to the left of the footline):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand\FootlineText{The text that goes in the footline}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=\paperwidth,leftskip=0.5cm,rightskip=0.5cm]{}
    \FootlineText
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[height=10pt]{logo}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\author{Some Author}
\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first line (`\PassOptionsToPackage`) was used only to make the example compilable for everyone by replacing the actual images with black rectangles; do *not* use that line in your actual code. Of course, feel free to adapt my example according to your needs.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! It's almost perfect, only the vertical position of the logo should be changed (lowered) a bit (without changing the position of the text). What's the best way to do that?

Comment: @Ailurus: you can include the logo using something like `\raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[height=10pt]{logo}}` with a convenient length instead of `1ex`

Comment: that's also what I thought. But it moves the text upwards (I think because the image is on the same line as the text). So should I make two boxes, or do something different?

Comment: Of course, using this `\raisebox` I can move the text upwards (by applying it to the image :D), and then move down the `\beamercolorbox`. It works, but is this the way I should use it?

Comment: @Ailurus: well, there are some other ways, you could use a `\parbox` for the text and another one for the logo and then move vertically the logo inside its `\parbox` (the second optional argument of `\parbox` lets you explicitly set the height of the box); in this way, the shifting of the logo won't affect the text.