# How can I add more line to my beamer presentation title side?

Tags: beamer

MY title page looks like this now:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\title{The title}

\author{The author}   

\date{\today}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

I want to add one more line, and I don't know how to do it. I found the \institute command, but it is not suited for me.

Comment: Without redefining the template, `\titlegraphic{One more line}` might suit.

Comment: You mean like a subtitle? → `\subtitle{Additional Line}`

Comment: How can I make the date to be the last one?

Comment: You have to [redefine the titlepage](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/how-to-customize-titlepage-in-beamer).

Comment: Also, what was wrong with `\institute`?

Comment: It uses smaller font and I want to write there my consultant's name

Comment: You can change the fontsize of the institute with `\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\normalsize}`.

Comment: As the line you want to add kind of belongs to the author you could also do something like that: `\author{The author\\The Consultant}`

Comment: Of course, you don't HAVE to use \maketitle.  You could just format the slide yourself.

Comment: @Benjamin It sounds like your comments solved the problem. Is it possible to convert them into an answer to remove the question from the list of unanswered?

Comment: How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to add an additional line with a consultant to the title page.

You can add a line break inside of the `\author{•}` macro with an additional space. As a consultant in a sense belongs to the author I would prefer this way.

```
\author{The author\\[0.5em]The Consultant}
```

If you don't need an institute on the title page, you can also use the `\institute{•}` macro (or any other field you don't need) and adjust the font size if desired.

```
\institute{The Consultant}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\normalsize}
```

And if these simple ways still do not satisfy your needs you can always redefine your title page as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/how-to-customize-titlepage-in-beamer).