# Subsubtitle Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I would like to have a title for my beamer presentation, a subtitle and a sub-subtitle. Of course I do not have problems with the title and the subtitle, but I cannot find a way to add a sub-sub-title. This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       PRESENTATION INFO        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\author{My name}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\institute{Department of Economics \\My University}
\date{June 2021}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       SLIDE DEFINITIONS       %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
\item In these lectures we will focus on dynamic panel data models (DPD).\medskip
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I tried to add

```
\subtitle{Subtitle \\ Sub-Sub-Title}
```

but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Any updates yet?

Answer (score 1):

I used `\subtitle{Subtitle\\[1em] Sub-Subtitle}` and it worked as expected. You must be more specific than `"[...] but it does not work. Any idea?"` if this is not what you want.

[image]

**Related**

- [How can I add more line to my beamer presentation title side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251503)

Comment: When I follow your suggestion, i cannot change line but a comma is put between the subtitle and the subsubtitle. Both stay in the same line. That was what I meant when I said that the solution does not work

Comment: May it depend on the specific template i am using? I am using a modified version of the Torino beamer template

Comment: Yes, maybe. It is best to provide code in your question that actually shows the problem.

Comment: If the code that you provide does not reproduce the problem then it is close to impossible to help / guess :)