# Customizing beamer title page?

Tags: beamer

I downloaded a presentation template from this link using beamer: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/conference-presentation

And it looks like this as following:

[image]

My question is, I will be giving a presentation of a paper of other authors. So I want to add my name and university below the authors' universities but above the date, like this

```
University of author 1
my name
my university
date
```

with the same font size of showing authors' names and universities.

I know `setbeamertemplate` and `addtobeamertemplate`, but since it's a small modification, I am wondering is that possible to do this without redoing the whole template?

current code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\title{Presentation Title}

\subtitle{Optional Subtitle}

\author{F.~Author\inst{1} \and S.~Another\inst{2}}
\institute[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  University of Somewhere
  \inst{2}%
  University of Elsewhere}
\date{Conference Name, 2013}

% Let's get started
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Cragfelt I was still editing. just added the current code.

Comment: You may take a look at this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/how-to-customize-titlepage-in-beamer

Comment: @Cragfelt that's what I referred to. It's basically redefining the template, which is what I want to avoid, given this should be a small modification.

Comment: @Cragfelt unless your answer is "no, we must redefine template for any modificaiton".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clean solution is to redefine the title page template. This approach will give you all opportunities to fine tune the result to fit your needs.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\title{Presentation Title}

\subtitle{Optional Subtitle}

\author{F.~Author\inst{1} \and S.~Another\inst{2}}
\institute[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  University of Somewhere
  \inst{2}%
  University of Elsewhere}
\date{Conference Name, 2013}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    % ----------------------- new
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}my name
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}my university
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    % ------------------------
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However on your on risk and with the warning that this is a) a dirty hack and b) might cause problems with the pdf properties if you don't give a short institute which can even render some pdf viewers unable to open your pdf - be warned!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\title{Presentation Title}

\subtitle{Optional Subtitle}

\author{F.~Author\inst{1} \and S.~Another\inst{2}}
\institute[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  University of Somewhere
  \inst{2}%
  University of Elsewhere\par
  my name\par
  my university}
\date{Conference Name, 2013}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```