# change color of title in custom title page

Tags: beamer

I'm using the custom title page shown in this [SE post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/how-to-customize-titlepage-in-beamer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
  \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
  \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
  \bigskip
  \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
  \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
  \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}
\title{A customized title page}
\subtitle{for demonstration}
\author{Stefan Kottwitz}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

but I can't figure out how to change the color of the title

down in my .sty file I tried adding

`\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red,fg=white`}

but that didn't work

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the title to take the `fg` and `bg` color of template `title`, you have to change the `title page` template, add a `beamercolorbox`, as in: `\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\textwidth,sep=1em]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\end{beamercolorbox}`

Then you can apply the color as in your example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9\textwidth,sep=1em]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\end{beamercolorbox}
    \usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par
    \bigskip
    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par
    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par
    \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate\par
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic
}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=red,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{subtitle}{fg=blue}

\title{A customized title page}
\subtitle{for demonstration}
\author{Stefan Kottwitz}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware, that you need to set the `subtitle` color appropriately, otherwise it will be white on white.